# How to get only the name of my PDF file

Tags: java, filenames

I'm developing a project for college which consist reading a CSV file and converting that to a PDF file. That part is fine, I have already done that.

In the end I need to show the name of the PDF file without the full path of where it was created. In other words, I just want the to show the name.

I search a lot to see if there is a simple method that show the name like Java has to show only the name of the File like

```
file.getName();
```

Comment: You should have something like this: response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"myReport.pdf\"");

Comment: Tags changed because this is not a question about iText but a question about filenames in standard Java code.

Comment: @gokcand that is in fact worth an answer, maybe with a bit of html (the link) and `response.getOutputStream()`.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use iText to create a PDF file, *your code* sets the target which usually is an `OutputStream`. If you use a `FileOutputStream` there, *you know* the file it writes to.

Thus, all you have to do to **to show the name of the PDF File** is to ***inspect your own code and check which target it sets***.

Comment: As mkl states, you define the name yourself in your code. The PDF file itself, that is: all the bytes that together form the PDF document, isn't aware of its name. There is no information about the name inside the document. In some cases, e.g. if the document only exists in memory, **there is no file name!** (Because there is no file on disk, only a byte array in memory.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `getBaseName` in [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/).

> **`getBaseName`**
>
> ```
> public static String getBaseName(String filename)
> ```
>
> Gets the base name, minus the full path and extension, from a full
>   filename.
>
> This method will handle a file in either Unix or Windows format. The
>   text after the last forward or backslash and before the last dot is
>   returned.
>
> ```
> a/b/c.txt --> c
> a.txt --> a
> a/b/c --> c
> a/b/c/ --> ""
> ```
>
> The output will be the same irrespective of the machine that the code
>   is running on.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - `filename` - the filename to query, null returns null
>
> **Returns:**
>
> - the name of the file without the path, or an empty string if none exists. Null bytes inside string will be removed

Source: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getBaseName(java.lang.String)

If you also need the extension, use `getExtension`. Which would probably always be `.pdf`, but you know, it's perfectly valid to have a PDF file without the `.pdf` filename extension. No sane person would do that but it is better to be prepared for insane users.